# TypeError: Planet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

# Create your models here.

class Planet(models.Model):
  name: models.CharField(max_length=50)
  number: models.IntegerField()
```

I used python shell to run:

```
python manage.py shell
from planet_universe.models import Planet
large_jupiter = Planet(name="Jupiter1", number=1)
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: Planet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'.

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Use `=`, not `:` when you define fields, right now you are making annotations, not defining fields: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/a-certain-field-does-not-appear-in-the-migrations-and-in-the-database-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=` instead of `:` like this:

```
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

# Create your models here.

class Planet(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  number = models.IntegerField()
```